# Парсер кода на c# для создания документации

Tags: c#, документация

Есть проект на asp.net mvc4 c#. Пишу интеграционные тесты. Необходимо по ним генерировать документацию--она же и тест кейс и комментарии к коду. Стандартная генерация xml файла по  тегам типа ///summary  не устраивает.Потому что документация именно для меня. И нет нужды описывать  методы с параметрами. Нужно комментарии (которые конечно придется писать строго) которые ВНУТРИ метода извлекать из файла исходного кода и помещать в например *.doc.
 Вопрос: Есть ли парсеры способные вытащить комментарии к коду из исходных файлов* .cs и поместить в какой нибудь текстовый формат(txt,rtf). Или придется писать свой.(сейчас читаю про Ndoc,Doxygen,JavaDoc--но еще не понял их возможностей применительно к своим нуждам)

Comment: попробовал Doxygen, кажется это то что надо! Если писать комментарии к коду через /// тройной слэш--он их вытаскивает!Только огорчает что в rtf файле комментарии на русском козябрами. Налеюсь это поправимо.Пробую работать дальше!

Comment: В Файле конфига Doxygen есть параметр INPUT_ENCODING, через него проблемы с кодировкой можно поправить

Comment: Спасибо Spawn за вникание в проблему, но это не помогло.
# раньше тут было указано INPUT_ENCODING = UTF-8
INPUT_ENCODING         = windows-1251

# раньше тут было указано DOXYFILE_ENCODING = UTF-8
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = windows-1251 
в Html  и так все гут. Заменил  UTF-8 на windows-1251 ПРОБЛЕМА ОСТАЛАСЬ.
 ---К СОЖАЛЕНИЮ МНЕ НУЖЕН ИМЕННО RTF И он остался с козябрами :(

Comment: Посмотри вот в [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg145034.aspx), вдруг найдёшь то что нужно.

Comment: Добрый день Аlex. Я в английском не как рыба в воде к сожалению(тогда и в коде мог бы делать комментарии по английски--и Doxygen использовать без проблем--то то и оно.)поэтому не совсем понял из оригинала(я еще на эту тему погуглил)как CodeDom может решить мою задачу. Если Вас не затруднит, напишите немного подробнее как с помощью CodeDom можно вытащить комментарии к коду из исходников.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт! Doxygen РУЛИТ!!!! Спасибо всем за участие!